# Xamarin.Forms app, works in simulator, started hanging on iOS Devices: dynamic-codesigning entitlement Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My app has started failing on devices seemingly out of the blue. When debugging it just hangs and sits there. Doesn't crash. I've found the following errors in the device log:

```
Error (0) / kernel(Sandbox): TUE.myiOSApp(629) System Policy: MAP_JIT requires the dynamic-codesigning entitlement
Error (222) / DTServiceHub(FrontBoardServices): [FBSSystemService][0x658f] Sending request to open "com.MyAppName”
Error (589) / SpringBoard(FrontBoard): [com.MyAppName] Provision violated for watchdog scene-create: <FBSProcessResourceProvision: 0x1c54fa400; allowance: <; FBSProcessResourceAllowance; type: realTime; timeValue: 18.57s>; violated: YES>
Error (589) / SpringBoard(KeyboardArbiter): [<_UIKeyboardArbiterHandle: 0x1c4115720; PID 631: com.MyAppName <(null)>; hosting PIDs {(
Error (589) / SpringBoard(KeyboardArbiter): -[_UIKeyboardArbiter runOperations:onHandler:]_block_invoke Failed to access <_UIKeyboardArbiterHandle: 0x1c4115720; PID 631: com.MyAppName <(null)>; hosting PIDs {(
```

I noticed another line that mentioned the process wasn't killed by the OS because it was being debugged.

This started happening right after I added a new device to the developer profile at the Apple Developer portal. I redownloaded the profile and installed it in xCode and in Visual Studio for Mac. The first time I ran the app on the new device, it ran successfully and I could debug. After that it started freezing. It also freezes on the old device I had been debugging successfully on just moments prior.

I've tried cleaning the solution, deleting all bin/obj folders. Restarting the device. Rebooting my Mac, etc.. nothing works.

I've dug around a little bit regarding the MAP_JIT error, however, the only answers I've found is to ensure Xcode is up to date. I'm on Xcode 11.3.1 and the command line tools are installed.

I updated to the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac which did not solve the issue

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Sean

Comment: Try to right click your iOS project > properties > iOS Bundle Signing,
Change the platform to iPhone and delete the Entitlements.plist there:

Comment: Thanks. However, the error above seems to have resolved after I reset my provisioning profile from "Automatic" directly to my development profile. I believe after I added the new device and redownloaded the profile, VS for Mac defaulted the setting back to Automatic which doesn't work. My app now runs on devices after I upload it. However, your response has raised a question: are you suggesting that in general, I should *not* have an Entitlements.plist selected for non-release configuration?

Comment: I think you should choose the `Entitlements.plist` when you need them,and on my side,`Manual Provisioning` is the default setting.